# How do I select a matching html element that is not the event using javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg

I am creating a tooltip that when hovered on a bar chart, it pulls information from datasets in the event and from information in a bar representing the same month but in a different year. However, I cannot seem to write a querySelector that matches that criteria.

Here's my html simplified for this example:

```
<div class="graph-wrapper">
  <svg>
   <g>
     <rect data-month="January" data-count="5380" data-year="2019"></rect>
     <rect data-month="February" data-count="4414" data-year="2019"></rect>
     <rect data-month="March" data-count="5339" data-year="2019"></rect>
   </g>
   <g>
     <rect data-month="January" data-count="5177" data-year="2020"></rect>
     <rect data-month="February" data-count="4466" data-year="2020"></rect>
     <rect data-month="March" data-count="3775" data-year="2020"></rect>
   </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

And then here is my querySelector:

```
let matchingElement = document.querySelector(`.graph-wrapper rect:not([data-year='${event.target.dataset.year}']),.graph-wrapper rect[data-month='${event.target.dataset.month}']`)
```

In summary, my querySelector is attempting to select the rect that has the same month in its dataset as the event.target but a different year.

Let me know if I need to share additional info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the top of my head, hope it works:

```
let data = [];
$("rect").on("hover", function() {
  data = [];
  let $this = $(this);
  let month = $this.attr('data-month');  
  $("rect").each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('data-month') == month && $(this).attr('data-year') != $this.attr('data-year')) {
      data.push({
       month: month,
       year: $(this).attr('data-year'),
       count: $(this).attr('data-count'),
       rect: $(this)
      });
    }
  });
});
```

In array "data" you should have all the info of the month you selected of all the years.
(BTW, I used jQuery it's simpler to write it for me, hope it's OK)

Comment: I am actually not using jquery on this site. The only library is d3. However, l don't think that would accomplish what I am trying to do. This would only push data to the array from just the event, right? And I need info from the event AND its matching rect from a different year. I don't really use jquery, so perhaps I am interpreting your answer incorrectly.

Comment: I also edited my question so that the querySelector matches the HTML in my question.

Comment: OK, I added rect in data so you'll have matching rect. Sorry, to rewrite it into plain Javascript would take a lot of time...

Comment: It's all good. Basically you split it up using a boolean statement, right? I had considered that as an option, but I was hoping to do it with querySelector.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is in vanilla JS:

```
let dataArray = [];
let rects = document.querySelectorAll(
    ".graph-wrapper rect[data-month]"
  );
  rects.forEach((rect) => {
    rect.addEventListener("mouseenter", (event) => {
      rects.forEach((rect) => {
        if (
          rect.dataset.month === event.target.dataset.month &&
          rect.dataset.year !== event.target.dataset.year
        ) {
          dataArray.push(rect.dataset.month);
          dataArray.push(rect.dataset.year);
          dataArray.push(rect.dataset.count);
        }
      });
```